# Is secp256k1 really a field?

Tags: python, elliptic-curve

I know my algebra is rusty, but isn't the following an identity operation: multiplying an element of a GF by the cardinal of the field (the modulus)? I wrote a program to verify it but couldn't:

```
from ecpy.curves import Curve, Point  # I use Python 2.7

def bin256(num):
  """binary conversion, returns a binary string, MSB first and LSB last"""
  return '{:0256b}'.format(num)

def ec_multiply(P, d):
  """double-and-add algo. Index decreasing, same naming as Wikipedia:
     P is a point on the curve
     d is a long
     returns P*d"""
  Q = None
  for bit in map(int, bin256(d)):
    if Q is not None:
      Q = Q + Q
    if bit:
      if Q is None:
        Q = P
      else:
        Q = Q + P
  return Q

def main():
  """Picks a random point on secp256k1 and multiply it by the modulus 
     of secp256k1 and print the result."""
     cv = Curve.get_curve('secp256k1')
     N = Point(0x65d5b8bf9ab1801c9f168d4815994ad35f1dcb6ae6c7a1a303966b677b813b00,
               0xe6b865e529b8ecbf71cf966e900477d49ced5846d7662dd2dd11ccd55c0aff7f, cv)
  MODULUS = 2**256 - 2**32 - 2**9 - 2**8 - 2**7 - 2**6 - 2**4 - 1

  Q = ec_multiply(N, MODULUS)
  print 'Q: %064x %064x' % (Q.x, Q.y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

But I get a different point:

```
Q: d113d66bf911fbf026b2a3e24c96bba45ca2d2b130cbf312a36e584249153090 56cabae3704f1c5a7957cbb1d9e2f6198337c59c02b2974d32fb7501b7e287d2
```

I expected `Q: 65d5b8bf..., e6b865e5...` instead.

**Any idea why multiplying by the modulus is not working in *secp256k1*?** Thanks in advance.

Notes:

- I am using the python elliptic curve library [ecpy](https://github.com/elliptic-shiho/ecpy/blob/master/ecpy/elliptic_curve/EllipticCurve.py) which just works, I've tested against another library (py_ecc, pure python) and I get consistent results.
- The multiplication over secp256k1 uses the double-and-add algo from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add) where the index is decreasing because I start from the MSB.
- I use [this excellent paper](https://github.com/bellaj/Blockchain/blob/6bffb47afae6a2a70903a26d215484cf8ff03859/ecdsa_bitcoin.pdf) that explains everything about EC and how to implement them.

Comment: It is a group, not a field. If you multiple a point by the *order* of the group you should get the identity. The prime modulus is *not* the order of the group. The order is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141

Comment: That works, thanks! Sorry I mixed up groups, rings, fields.

Comment: It seems that it is indeed a field : "secp256k1 field is a prime field and therefore isomorphic to a ring of integers modulo a prime" and "Technically, every prime field is a Galois field" https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/what-does-the-curve-used-in-bitcoin-secp256k1-look-like

Comment: You have misunderstood that statement and left out the critical word "the" in front of "secp256k1". The curve is defined over a field, but the curve itself has a group structure with properties distinct from the underlying field.

Comment: "**It is a group**" wasn't clear enough for me but thanks to your clarification it's all fine, thanks!